# Forcing a flat edge when using the subdivision surface modifier

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, geometry

I'm trying to create a low poly bathtub in Blender that I intend to print off using a Resin  3D printer.

I'm using the Solidify modifier to give the walls sufficient thickness to print, and the Subdivision surface modifier to smooth the low poly surface.

This if perfect for the sides of the bathtub which are nice and smooth despite it being low poly, but I want the top and bottom to be a perfectly flat surfaces. Essentially, I want to create a rim and a base.

Other than putting in multiple loop cuts is there any way that I can force the top and bottom to be flat rather than being rounded off by the subdivision modifier?

I've deliberately left the bottom of the tub open because I'm going to place a false floor in it to represent the water and I want to be access it from underneath.

enter image description here

[image]
[image]

The bottom image shows a rounded base, I need it to be flat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Edit mode*, select your top and bottom edge loops by Alt+Left clicking on them, press N to bring out the side menu, and in the *Item* tab, set *Mean Crease* to 1.

[image]

Comment: How did I not know this?

Comment: You learn every day :)

Answer (score 1):

Select the edges you want to crease, press Shift + E to activate the Crease Tool and move your mouse to set the amount of creasing. A value of 1.0 means 100% creasing. You can also type in values with your numpad and press Enter when done.

[image]

Comment: This also looks like it could be a good answer, could you please explain this a little more.